# Menu hide/show ao clicar

Tags: jquery

Estou com uma duvida estou utilizando Wordpress
esse é meu jquery para pegar o link que eu estou clicando e atravez de uma ancora `ID #` ele desce o scroll ate o conteudo desejado porem preciso que esconda tudo e quando clicar apareça somente o conteúdo clicado.

```
$('.sub-menu a').click(function() {
    var anchor;
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
        anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
    }

    if (anchor !== undefined) { 
        show().$(anchor) 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(anchor).offset().top}, 2000);
    }

});
```

Comment: Cara coloca pelo menos seu HTML ai, está meio difícil de entender o que vc quer...

Comment: resolvi fiz assim $('.sub-menu a').click(function() {
        var anchor;
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
        }
        $('.id-sub').slideUp("slow");
         if (anchor !== undefined) {
            $(anchor).slideDown("slow");
            
         }
        
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.sub-menu a').click(function() {
    var anchor;
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
        anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
    }
    $('.id-sub').slideUp("slow");
     if (anchor !== undefined) {
        $(anchor).slideDown("slow").addClass('#sobre');


     }

});
```